# git bashで Cannot activate python venv, aborting...というエラーでました。どうすればよいですか？

Tags: git-bash, python-venv

git bashで Cannot activate python venv, aborting...というエラーでました。どうすればよいですか？

Comment: エラーが出るまでに行なった手順等も質問に追記してみてください。